# Issues with SharePoint Security Trimmer control

Tags: 2013, master-page, security-trimming

I notice that using the security trimming control (say for RibbonBox) only hides the content, I want something like display:none, can we achieve this?:

CASE 1:

```
  <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="EditListItems">
    <div id="ribbonBox" style="background-color:red">

    //code of ribbon with the buttons for edit/share/follow/fullscreen

    </div>
    </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

CASE 2:

```
 <div id="ribbonBox" style="background-color:red">
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="EditListItems">

        //code of ribbon with the buttons for edit/share/follow/fullscreen

        </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
</div>
```

When a user with only read permission logs in, then he cannot see the contents of the div tag (this is perfect!), however:-

CASE 1.  The div itself is not collapsed.

CASE 2.  The div does not get the red color.

How can I achieve the CASE 1 and CASE 2 scenario?

**UPDATE**

CASE 1 is solved by enclosing the security trimmed control around the `<div id="s4-ribbonrow">`

Comment: You can use EmitDiv in the SecurityTrimmedControl to make it not render a containing div, hence only whay you put inside of the control will be rendered

Comment: How does emitdiv help? I tried setting it to true, also false, yet the div tag is still there

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:
div id=”div1' style=”display:none”

now add following block

Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID=”SPSecurityTrimmedControl1″ runat=”server” PermissionsString=”AddAndCustomizePages”
script type=”text/javascript”
document.getElementById(“div1”).style.display = “block”;
/script
/Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Please find more details
http://subhasis07.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: CASE 1 or CASE 2?